# How I print all guild name and number of members?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

## Discord.js Version 11.4.2

How I print all the guild names and their number of members?

```js
if (message.content === '!list') {
  message.channel.send("Checking ....")
  console.log(/* all guild name and number of members */)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if(message.content === '!scheck'){
   client.guilds.forEach(member => {
    console.log(`${member.name} - ${member.memberCount}`)
    message.channel.send(`${member.name} - ${member.memberCount} members | id guild :  ${member.id} | owner is : ${member.owner.user.tag}`)
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
(your guild variable here).members.forEach(member => {
   console.log(member.user.tag);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running Discord.js v11, this few lines should do the trick :

```
let guildsInfo = [];
client.guilds.forEach(guild => {
    guildsInfo.push(`${guild.name} - ${guild.users.size} users`);
});
// Then log the data to the console (You can also use "message.channel.send" if the character amount is smaller than 2048)
console.log(guildsInfo.join('\n') + `That's a total of ${client.guilds.size} guilds and ${client.users.size} users.`);
```

I hope this was what you were looking for ! :)